# Import step model into HFSS

Tags: simulation, cad

I have a step file and I want to simulate it in HFSS but it seams that the structure it is not made with solids, but with attached sheets because when I import it in HFSS I cannot define materials and everything is under sheet.
Do you know a way to convert it in a 3D model to be able to simulate it? Either in HFSS or AutoCad

Comment: You have to make sure to define the structure in AutoCad as a 3d Solid. I am not able to open up HFSS for now, but I believe you can use the sheets to define solids. It would be helpfull if you could post some more info, such as images of the actual model in HFSS, so that we can understand what you are talking about.

Comment: Do you have an electrical engineering question related to electronics or electrical design?

Comment: More a software problem related to electrical @Joren Vaes you're saing that I can transform 3D model made by 2D figures (sheets and whatever) directly in AutoCad? Because I know that in HFSS I can use sheet thickness function, but it does not allow me to convert it then in a 3D model. Actually give me an error (operation unsuccessful)

Comment: @Shika93 I'm not sure how it is possible in AutoCAD, I mainly work with Inventor.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with electronics design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a way.

Once imported the `.step` file HFSS will give as model a group, therefore first I ungrupped. Then selecting the entire object, is possible to convert the 2D sheet model in a 3D model with `Modeler -> Surface -> Create Object From Face`. Then probably (at least this is what I had to do to simulate it) there will be some errors in the structure that need to be solved before launch the simulation. To do it `Modeler -> Model Analysis ->`then select `Analyse Surface Mesh` and if it give no error is possible to `Validate` the project and check if the 3D model has the green check, otherwise `Analyse Objects` choose the `Check Level` and try to heal the model (automatically or manual)

Thanks to everyone for the support anyway. Helped me to find the solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a spaceclaim license to import step models. Try a different model for the license you have, you can import a 3D .sat .sab ACIS file or 2D .dxf .dwg without a license.